# GPUImage: Mask blur

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm using `GPUImage` to blur a circular shaped image. Over the image, I have circular "frame" image. The problem is that the blur makes the image stretch outside the bounds of the original frame image.

I could mask the image with (like `CALayer`, `cornerRadius` then `maskToBounds`) but that really slow when I have a lot of these images.

Is it possible to mask the blurry image with `GPUImage` in a fast way?

Thanks.

[image]

```
GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter = [GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter new];
blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 15;
self.blurryThumbNail.image = [blurFilter imageByFilteringImage:self.profileImage.image];
```

Comment: use fast implementation of gaussian blur

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you post some code please?

Comment: sure, see [here](http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html)

Comment: sorry, I mean this: "gaussian filter have an ability "separate" ". so, you could implement gaussian blur as two linear gaussian blurs (not a square, two-coordinate, but a line, single-coordinate filter)

Comment: @gaussblurinc - Which is exactly what all of the blurs in GPUImage do. They all separate the blur into X and Y passes, and even leverage mid-texel sampling to significantly reduce the number of reads involved. This is all performed GPU-side, so you're going to be hard pressed to find a CPU-based implementation that comes close to their performance on mobile devices. As Tomas indicates, I describe this in detail here: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2013/10/21/optimizing-gaussian-blurs-mobile-gpu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a handy filter for that: `GPUImageGaussianBlurPositionFilter`

You specify the *blurCenter* and *blurSize*. Note that coordinates are between 0.0 and 1.0.

`GPUImageGaussianBlurPositionFilter` is a subclass of `GPUImageFilterGroup` and basically it's a 2 step filter. First it applies a blur using the `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter` (the one you're using) then it combines the result with the original unblurred one using the specified parameters.

There's an interesting article about the current implementation of `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter` on Brad Larson's blog [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2013/10/21/optimizing-gaussian-blurs-mobile-gpu)

Comment: @TomasCarmin: does this filter is an implementation of "linear gaussian"?

Comment: @gaussblurinc Yes, the filter is optimized by combining vertical and horizontal blurs.

Comment: so, +1 for your answer :)